# Is MultiColumn- explorer widget available in swt?

Tags: swt, eclipse-rcp, jface

As windows provide to view multiple files in column as i attached in the image.
Is there any SWT Widget available to display/arrange objects in multi column way similar to windows?

I have already used **"Row layout(SWT.Vertical)"** but i am facing some performance issue while painting if it has more than 2000+ objects.

While windows explorer doesn't have this kind of performance issue if it has more than 6000 data.

I can't use table viewer as it has each row as one object, but in my requirement I need to have object in each cell

Do let me know if any in-built widget is available in JFace/SWT for multi column view explorer to arrange objects.

Thanks

[image]

Comment: For large contents you can use the `SWT.VIRTUAL` flag and `ILazyContentProvider` (for `TableViewer`)

Comment: I can't use table viewer as it has each row as one object, but in my requirement I need to have object in each cell

Comment: The content provider can use a container object for the row containing the cell objects. It is often the case that a content provider needs to use additonal objects. You could also look at [NatTable](https://www.eclipse.org/nattable/) which may be able to do what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't able to find direct JFace/SWT widget for this requirement. May be others senior members can give pointers.

For your requirement [Nebula Gallery Widget](https://www.eclipse.org/nebula/widgets/gallery/gallery.php)
`NOTE: THIS WIDGET AND ITS API ARE STILL UNDER DEVELOPMENT, as written in its Javadoc`

Code goes below :

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Display display = new Display();
        Image itemImage = new Image(display, Program.findProgram("jpg").getImageData()); //$NON-NLS-1$
        Shell shell = new Shell(display);
        shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());

        Gallery gallery = new Gallery(shell, SWT.H_SCROLL | SWT.MULTI | SWT.VIRTUAL);

        // Renderers
        NoGroupRenderer gr = new NoGroupRenderer();
        gr.setMinMargin(2);
        gr.setItemHeight(20);
        gr.setItemWidth(100);
        gr.setAutoMargin(true);
        gallery.setGroupRenderer(gr);

        ListItemRenderer ir = new ListItemRenderer();
        gallery.setItemRenderer(ir);

        GalleryItem group = new GalleryItem(gallery, SWT.NONE);

        for (int i = 0; i < 20000; i++) {
            GalleryItem item = new GalleryItem(group, SWT.NONE);
            if (itemImage != null) {
                item.setImage(itemImage);
            }
            item.setText("Item " + i); //$NON-NLS-1$
        }

        shell.pack();
        shell.open();

        while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch())
                display.sleep();
        }
        display.dispose();
    }
}
```

Output :

[image]